# Why my UI is not updated while CoreData is?

Tags: swift, list, swiftui, core-data, combine

The problem I have seems to be only of UI, is this: beyond when I start the app, if in a tab I change a webApp to favorite, I should see in the list of general notifications, among others, its notifications. if I remove the webApp from the list of favorites, even the related notifications should not be shown. this seems to happen in coreData, but not in the ui. I do not have this problem with the WebApps, which update without problem.

The assumption is that even if I have saved on coreData the notifications of not currently preferred apps, I have to see only the notifications of those marked as favorites. so I want to have in the “Unread” list all the notifications that: have the variable "isRead == false" And have the variable "isPreferred" of their WebApp (a relationshipOneToOne) == to true inside the "Read" list exactly the same, but with "isRead == true" when I start the app, everything works, but if I change the state of an application later (then changing its isPreferred status), in this tab, the lists do not update, while in others it does (like the one that shows favorite WebApps).

I also tried to use a bool type @State var to update every time the list appears (via onAppear) but nothing changes.

If I print the list, inside the computed var, everything seems to work, I have the correct results, CoreData is updated without problems but the UI does not update.

```
import SwiftUI

struct NotificationsListView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var classFromEntryPoint: ClassFromEntryPoint
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var managedObjectContext
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    /// FetchRequest for UNREAD notifications
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: ReceivedNotification.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ReceivedNotification.id, ascending: true)],
        predicate: NSPredicate(format: "isRead == false AND ownerAppRelationOneToOne.isPreferred == true")
    ) var unreadNotificationsOnCD: FetchedResults<ReceivedNotification>
    
    var filteredUnreadNotificationsOnCD: [ReceivedNotification] {
        let downloadedIDs = Set(classFromEntryPoint.downloadedAppsList.map { $0.id })
        return unreadNotificationsOnCD
            .filter { downloadedIDs.contains($0.ownerAppRelationOneToOne?.id ?? "N/D") }
    }
    
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    /// FetchRequest for READ notifications
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: ReceivedNotification.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ReceivedNotification.id, ascending: true)],
        predicate: NSPredicate(format: "isRead == true AND ownerAppRelationOneToOne.isPreferred == true")
    ) var readNotificationsOnCD: FetchedResults<ReceivedNotification>
    
    var filteredReadNotificationsOnCD: [ReceivedNotification] {
        let downloadedIDs = Set(classFromEntryPoint.downloadedAppsList.map { $0.id })
        return readNotificationsOnCD
            .filter { downloadedIDs.contains($0.ownerAppRelationOneToOne?.id ?? "N/D") }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            List {
                NotificationSection(title: "Unread", notifications: Array(filteredUnreadNotificationsOnCD))
                
                NotificationSection(title: "Read", notifications: Array(filteredReadNotificationsOnCD))
            }
            .hideScrollBackgroundIfAvailableIOS16Modifier()
            .backgroundImage2_WithGeometryReader()
            
            .navigationBarTitle("Notifications")

            Text("Select a notification on left menu")
        }
        .environmentObject(classFromEntryPoint) //available in all views down

    }

    
}

struct NotificationsListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NotificationsListView()
            .environmentObject(ClassFromEntryPoint())
    }
}



//MARK: - Accessory  view

struct NotificationSection: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var classFromEntryPoint: ClassFromEntryPoint
    
    var title: String
    ///Array to be used in case you wanted to give chance to delete multiple elements./
    var notifications: [ReceivedNotification]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Section(header: Text(title)) {
            if notifications.isEmpty {
                Text("No notification")
            } else {
                ForEach(notifications, id: \.id) { notification in
                    //with a button the whole area can be tappable
                    Button {
                        classFromEntryPoint.markNotificationAsRead(notification)
                    } label: {
                        NotificationCell(notification: notification)
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to pass the results of the fetch request to NotificationSection and do the filtering (computed property) inside that view. As for why the view isn’t update I believe it’s because it is static in the sense there is no component in it that directly depends on the fetch requests or any other type that might trigger a redraw of the UI.

Comment: I'm afraid that performing the filter inside the section could slow the app. At this moment, I bypassed calling two func in my environment class in wich I perform a fetchRequest, filter, and assign it to two published vars. I call this funcs in onAppear and when tap on the notification inside the section. The point is, if the issue is anything is triggering the update, as you and I suppose, adding a @State var uuid then I change it I.E. in on appear or when update the notification status by tapping it it should be update the UI, right? it is not happening!

Comment: You would be doing the same filtering you do now in your computed properties so I don’t understand how that would slow down the app. Also, what would it cost you to try just to see if it works?

Comment: oh, maybe I was not clear! I'm going to test it, but I read that SwiftUI has some issue if you put too much computational effort in annitiaded views. Don't know if it's still true and how real is the issue. I will update this Friday